# What in the world does this vimscript do?

Tags: vim, haskell

Full source here: http://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=10391

The line is:

```
    silent %s/[^λ←→≲≳≡≠⇒»∙∀\\\-!#$%&*+/<=>?@\^|~.]\@<=\\\([^λ←→≲≳≡≠⇒»∙∀\\\-!#$%&*+/<=>\?@\^|~.]\)/λ\1/eg
```

Someone please decipher this for me. The larger script is intended to unicode-ify some operators in Haskell into more familiar mathematical equivalents.

Comment: If this is "regular", I can't imagine what an irregular one would look like ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Full explanation for the line here: http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/8b0tf/haskell_unicode_cuteness_for_vim/

Answer (score 6):

As the author of that line, I can translate. Complicated regular expressions are often 'write-only' and this relies on a vim regex extension.

The purpose of this is to make sure that it doesn't do the replacement of `\` with a pretty printed `λ` in the middle of an operator like `\\`.

It checks to make sure that the character that precedes us in the buffer is not a valid operator symbol (the meaning of everything everything up to the `\@<=`). The `\@<=` is a 'zero width match look behind', which only succeeds if the stuff to the left of it occurs, but doesn't include it in the resulting match.

And then the `\([^...]\)` part checks to make sure that the stuff that follows us is a non-symbol as well, in which case, we match it, and then include it in the output thanks to the `\1` in the result.

Note, this isn't perfect. Unfortunately, It will still replace backslashes inside of strings, but it works rather well.